# How can I hyperlink a method from a Python module in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

While writing documentation using Sphinx, I know that I can link to a class by using [Intersphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/intersphinx.html):

```
:py:class:`logging.Logger`
```

But how do I link directly to a specific method, like `logging.Logger.warning()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use

```
:py:meth:`module.class.mymethodname`
```

Comment: Generally you can drop the `:py` prefix in Sphinx, as it is the [default domain](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html) - so that becomes `:meth:\`module.class.mymethodname\``. You might be working with more than one language though, in which case it might be useful to be explicit!